# check if output returns ValueError

Tags: python, valueerror

I want to retrieve the index of a character inside a python string. But when string is not found the function returns `ValueError: substring not found`

Since I have the function in an `if` statement it breaks my code.

How could i verify if the output of the following line of code does not give an `ValueError` output: `mystring.index('string I look for')`

Comment: You can use `try catch` to catch the exception

Comment: you need to provide smaple code, example and output, in order reproduce the problem

Answer (score 0):

You can just check it first by creating a mere function

```
def check(s, target):
    if target in s:
           return s.index(target)
    else:
           return None

s = 'Yeah, I\'m gonna take my horse to the old town road'

check(s, 'g')
# 10
```

Or with a lambda function, if you intend to use it just once or twice

```
check = lambda s, t: s.index(t) if t in s else None
s = 'Yeah, I\'m gonna take my horse to the old town road'

check(s, 'old')
# 37

s[37]
# 'o'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can catch the exception thrown by using `try except`:

```py
In [1]: s = "hello world"

In [1]: s = "hello world"

In [2]: s.index("a")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1a10a9a0bcff> in <module>
----> 1 s.index("a")

ValueError: substring not found

In [3]: try:
   ...:     s.index("a")
   ...: except ValueError:
   ...:     pass  # or do something else. This means that the character was not found
```

Answer (score 0):

See 8.3. Handling Exceptions [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html)

TRY / EXCEPT should do the trick. For example:

```
try:
    mystring.index('c')
except:
    print('substring not found')
```

this will return the index of character 'c' if it exists in the string, if not, it will do an action you specify.. in this case it will print "substring not found" and continues the code without breaking it

This will work with any error. If you wanted to be more specific and do different actions for different type of errors, you could also specify actions by error types... e.g.

```
except ValueError:
    <do something>
```